# input field still required after filling it using jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to write a basic script that fills Hot-spot wifi log-in username and password.
But I'm not programer...

I extract the page code using web inspector:

```
<div id="fixed_modalLogin" class="popup ng-scope" dir="ltr"
     ng-if="vm.isFixedPhoneFormShown">&gt;
  <div class="popup-overlay">
    <div class="popup-wrap a-center">
      <label class="exit" ng-click="vm.hidefixedPopup()">×</label>
      <form name="fixed_login_form"
            ng-submit="vm.fixedLoginPhone(fixed_login_form)"
            novalidate="" ng-hide="vm.inProgress"
            class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
        <header class="head text-left"
                ng-class="vm.layout==true ? 'text-right' : 'text-left'">
          <div class="h ng-binding"
               ng-bind-html="vm.ui.joodPopupText.value | trustedHtml">
            <p>Enjoy free internet for STC customers with fixed Internet
               bundles<br><br>If you forget the username or password please
               send an SMS to 900 with the code 1811 followed by the area
               code then your landline number for example
               (1811 01XXXXXXXX<br><br>
            </p>
          </div>
        </header>
        <main ng-class="vm.layout==true ? 'ar_main_free' : 'main_free'"
              class="main_free">
           <h4><span class="ng-binding">* Username</span></h4>
           <span class="ng-binding">xxx@stc.net.sa</span>
           <input ng-init="vm.user.username = ''" ng-model="vm.user.username"
                  name="username" required=""
                  class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
           <!-- ngIf: fixed_login_form.$submitted -->
           <h4><span class="ng-binding">* Password</span></h4>
           <input type="password" ng-init="vm.user.password = ''"
                  ng-model="vm.user.password" name="password" required=""
                  class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
           <!-- ngIf: fixed_login_form.$submitted -->
           <div class="form-group ng-isolate-scope" errors="vm.serverErrors" field="'base'">
             <!-- ngRepeat: error in vm.errors[vm.field] -->
           </div>
        </main>
        <footer class="footer">
          <button class="button" type="submit">
             <span class="ng-binding">LOGIN</span>
           </button>
        </footer>
      </form>
      <spinner ng-show="vm.inProgress" in-progress="vm.inProgress"
               class="ng-isolate-scope ng-hide">
         <div ng-class="vm.inProgress==true ? 'sk-fading-circle' : 'sk-fading-circle-landing'" 
              class="sk-fading-circle-landing">
           <div class="sk-circle1 sk-circle"></div>
           <div class="sk-circle2 sk-circle"></div>
           <div class="sk-circle3 sk-circle"></div>
           <div class="sk-circle4 sk-circle"></div>
           <div class="sk-circle5 sk-circle"></div>
           <div class="sk-circle6 sk-circle"></div>
           <div class="sk-circle7 sk-circle"></div>
           <div class="sk-circle8 sk-circle"></div>
           <div class="sk-circle9 sk-circle"></div>
           <div class="sk-circle10 sk-circle"></div>
           <div class="sk-circle11 sk-circle"></div>
           <div class="sk-circle12 sk-circle"></div>
           <div ng-class="vm.inProgress==true ? 'spinner-popup' : 'spinner'" class="spinner">
             <span class="ng-binding">LOADING</span>
           </div>
         </div>
       </spinner>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was able to write code the click and fill the username & password using app called "HelloGuestWifi" with below script:

```
try { document.querySelector("a[ng-click='vm.fixedLogin();']").click();
} catch(ee){ }

try{ jQuery("input[name='username']").val("ZZZZ@stc.net.sa");
} catch(ee){ }

try{ jQuery("input[name='password']").val("ZZZZ");} catch(ee){ }

try{ jQuery("span:contains('LOGIN')").click();} catch(ee){ }
```

Before ISP updates their sign-in page. this command line was working:
`try { document.querySelector("input[ng-init='vm.user.username']").Value("ZZZZ");} catch(ee){ }`

But now they changed the `ng-init='vm.user.username'` to `ng-init="vm.user.username = ''"`
So I tried to use jQuery instead.

But now the page says "Field is required" after the input field is filled with username and password.

is there a way to make this command work again `try { document.querySelector("input[ng-init='vm.user.username = ''']").Value("ZZZZ");} catch(ee){ }`

Thanks!

Comment: is there a way to tell the controller that those inputs fields were changed?
Just like the chrome auto-fill script or something.

Comment: The `ngModelController` listens for the `change` event. See [MDN Web API Reference - dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) and [jQuery API Reference - triggerHandler](https://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/).

Comment: with my little understanding, I tried to trigger a change like this 
`try{ jQuery("[ng-model]").trigger("change");} catch(ee){ }`
but still didn't work.

Comment: also 
`try{ jQuery("input[name='password']").val("ZZZZ").trigger("change");} catch(ee){ }` 
didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

well just looking at the code you provided. jquery val takes string or variable and I believe "ZZZZ" is not a variable.

```
try{ jQuery("input[name='password']").val("ZZZZ");} catch(ee){ }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. both still fill password input field but still says "Field is required"

Answer (score 0):

```
try{ jQuery("input[name='password']").val('ZZZZ');} catch(ee){ }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. both still fill password input field but still says "Field is required"

Comment: `try{ 
jQuery("input[name='password']").val('ZZZZ');
jQuery("input[name='password']").removeAttr('required');
} catch(ee){ }`

Comment: remove required attr as above.

Comment: I just tried your code to remove required Attribute, but it still not accepting.
there might be more than one validator ```"ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" ```

Comment: Remove `ng-invalid-required` class from input controls

Comment: `try{ jQuery("input").removeAttr("ng-invalid-required");} catch(ee){ }` didn't work.